# RewriteRule -- how to serve file from subdirectory, but show requested URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have http://domain.com properly redirecting to https://domain.com with:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

I want to be able to switch between dev/live subdirectories *without* altering the URL that displays in the browser.

I want `https://domain.com` to actually serve from a subdirectory i.e. index.php from one of the subdirectories:

`public_html/
        /site1/index.php
        /site2.index.php`

I've got this which does what I want for everything BUT the https://domain.com where it shows https://domain.com/site1/index.php whereas I want to hide the subdirectory information from the browser.

`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php [L]
```

'

I've lost count of the places I've taken various bits from so I may just have the order wrong or maybe I have to specify the directory index, but it all seems to bleed back into the URL shown in the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check on the html you're outputting to the client? the rewrites would be useless if you're outputting the subdirectory links in the first place. and if ALL requests have to go into that subdir, why not just make that subdir your document root, meaning you wouldn't need to rewrite at all?

Comment: No, all the internal links work fine, it's just the initial URL that gets the /site1/ fung in it.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to set a subdomain for 'devsite.domain.com' to point at the current development dir.  Can I just set DocumentRoot for the main and subdomains to point at the correct subdirectory and be done with it?

Comment: pretty much, especially if all your html paths/links are set up to NOT use `/site1`

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear.  The purpose of this is to allow someone who can edit .htaccess in public_html but cannot touch httpd.conf to switch the live site back and forth.  VirtualHost directives are only allowed in server context.